# Preference Connector

Tags: android

i was put on button click this:

```
PreferenceConnector.writeBoolean(getContext(), PreferenceConnector.IS_Table_Order, true
```

i was put on button click where other fragment open:

```
1.PreferenceConnector.readBoolean(getContext(), PreferenceConnector.IS_Table_Order, false

2.PreferenceConnector.readBoolean(getContext(), PreferenceConnector.IS_Table_Order, true
```

both condition 1 and 2 are used for other other task but problems are created that its not work true or false

Comment: I can't understand what your asking.  You also need to tell us what PreferenceConnector is-  it isn't part of Android.

Comment: its solution anybody have

Answer (score 0):

Your `readBoolean` method must return `Boolean`. It must look something like

```
public static boolean readBoolean(Context context, String key,
            boolean defValue) {
        return getPreferences(context).getBoolean(key, defValue);
    }
```

It must be used as

```
if(PreferenceConnector.readBoolean(getContext(),PreferenceConnector.IS_Table_Order, false){
//DoSomething
}
```

Comment: I answered it as per my understanding and as much as I understood. If my understanding is wrong, the one who asked the question can correct me. I was just giving it a try that I understood right or not.

Comment: *If my understanding is wrong, the one who asked the question can correct me. I was just giving it a try that I understood right or not. – Surbhi 57 mins ago* - instead of doing this.. if you are not sure if your understanding is right, you should ask for clarification before answering

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks for pointing. I will keep in mind from now onwards.